# iOS - after selecting Photo library option page is redirecting to SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios

In my application I am using SWRevealViewController to show side menu bar.
in side menu bar I have one option which need to load `UIWebView` in that I have photo selection option its displaying photo library and iCloud option. If I press on photo library option its redirecting page to SWRevealViewController. Giving error as

> Warning: Attempt to present UIImagePickerController: 0x7a2e1600> on
>   SWRevealViewController: 0x7aabc600> whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

This is my storyBoard Image[StoryBoardImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YysxB.png)

Comment: It would be easier to help seeing some code

Comment: Posting code will help to identify your problem.

Comment: I didn't used any code in uiwebview controller just I loaded the link in web view . Pressing one of the button in web view its displaying popup showing photo library and iCloud if I tap outside or if I press on any of the option its showing Attempt to present UIImagePickerController: 0x7a2e1600> on SWRevealViewController: 0x7aabc600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!  .

Comment: I used only this code to load the link in web view NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://oficinavirtualmp.coomeva.com.co/sor-web/registroSolicitud.xhtml"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 30.0];
        
        [_AutoWebView loadRequest:request];